# Translations of Kolmogorov Student Olympiads in Probability Theory

Tags: probability-theory, contest-math, stochastic-calculus, translation-request, mathematical-russian

I am deeply interested in Kolmogorov's probability contest whose tests could be found in English for the five first years but there is no English translation to its problems from round 6 onward.
I have put the links to the original Russian problems and would be grateful to the contribution of Russian speakers in this forum to translate the questions to English.

Many thanks in advance

- http://mech.math.msu.su/probab/olimpia/ol-sol.pdf
- http://mech.math.msu.su/probab/olimpia/olsol09.pdf

Comment: You are aware thet the first link starts with the fifth contest, not with the sixth?

Comment: Yes I reckon that the first link contains contests 5,6 and 7. Thanks

Comment: It may sound cynic, but there is in fact a Springer book "Russian for mathematicians" (e.g. it trains declination of nouns with Число (number) and adjectives with дистрибутивны (distributive) or the like). :)

Comment: Oh thank you for the reference. I think at some point I need to learn some russian given the abondance of russian math literature that has not been translated to English. I hope a russian speaker around will help for the time being. My post is also meant to draw the attention of forum members to this interesting contest

Comment: Do you want just the questions, or the solutions as well? I can probably translate the questions fairly quickly, but translating all the solutions as well will take longer (i.e., I probably won't have time to get it done until my exams are over in a couple weeks...)

Comment: Hi Jonathan

Just the questions :) Thanks

Comment: This type of question is neither disallowed by the FAQ nor explicitly recommended. However, it seems like a question that would be best handled on this site. The translated questions might prove good for the site.

Comment: I have raised [a question regarding this topic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6690/translation-of-mathematical-questions) on meta.

Comment: I also raised [such a question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6689/propose-new-tag-translation-request#comment23778_6689).

Comment: Your second link has "olsol09" in it, which makes it seem like you think it's the 9th contest, but it's contest 8 (acc. to the top of the file).

Comment: I translated the fifth contest questions (not solutions).

Comment: I've translated 6-8, but want to run through them again before I post them somewhere. There are some really cool problems in there.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I have uploaded KCd's translation of the questions for year 5 and my translation of the questions for years 6-8 [here](http://stat.duke.edu/~jcc69/kolmogorov.pdf).

Please let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 3):

This post is for links to problems in the translation that have been asked on the site:

[Problem 10, 7th Kolmogorov Student Olympiad in Probability Theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257874/estimate-variance-given-a-sample-of-size-one-7th-kolmogorov-student-olympiad)

(Also previously discussed in this [stats.SE question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44892/2970).)

Answer (score 0):

https://api.newton.ac.uk/website/v0/events/preprints/NI05043
this link also contains an archive of several editions of the Kolmogorov Cup contest.